# two arrayList into one in diff classes

Tags: android

hi, I have two listArrays in my class. I want to use a class in the activity class, but i want to put both in one arrayList which exists in a public class defined in all my apps. data name is Data 
My first class contains the next arrays:

```
//Class1

public static ArrayList<String> array1=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> array2=new ArrayList<String>();


//Data
public static ArrayList<Class1> getE = new ArrayList<Class1>();
```

well i tried to use an obj from class1 in Activity class to get the value from the listArray but the app crashed when run. That's why i want to put the values of the arrays into one array in the Data class. 
Next i show how i used the object:

```
//ActivityClass
Class1 c1=new Class1();
if(c1.array1.get(1)=="1")
    {
    return ;
     }
```

the first Question: how to put the value in the array1 and array2 into the array in Data class getE??

second Q: why the app crashed when i used the obj in ActiityClass?

```
09-25 07:03:04.888: E/UNIVERSITY(645): Size of List Before 0
09-25 07:03:06.948: I/dalvikvm(645): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.university.app.PersonalHome$1.onItemClick(PersonalHome.java:61)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.university.app.controls.CarouselAdapter.performItemClick(CarouselAdapter.java:261)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.university.app.controls.Carousel.onSingleTapUp(Carousel.java:964)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.university.app.controls.Carousel.onTouchEvent(Carousel.java:310)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5541)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-25 07:06:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 07:18:01.538: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: `getE.clear(); getE.addAll(array1); getE.addAll(array2);`

Comment: `c1.array1.get(1).equals("1")` and Avoid Static variables.

Comment: @st0le: the code from your first comment won't work -> different types!
Meral AB: please post the stack trace and improve your question's spelling.

Comment: @user714965, I didn't realize it was `Class`, Nice catch. :P

Comment: @user714965 i just added the logcat at the Question :)

Comment: @st0le i tried c1.array1.get(1).equals("1") but still the problem

Comment: @MeralAB: Have you seen the `NullPointerException`? You should check what happens in this line: `PersonalHome.java:61`. Obviously you are accessing a variable which is not initialized.

Comment: if(c1.array1.get(1).equals("1"))
this is the line but it's not null :(

Comment: Question 1:"how to put the value in the array1 and array2 into the array in Data class getE??" Why do you want to do like that?

Comment: @Bhavesh i want to use a values fro array1 and arraya2 into a ActivityClass i think to put them in one array that eas my work